# Grails how to make a properly join withCriteria

Tags: postgresql, grails

I have the following statement on **grails 2.0.3** that works fine 
**Query that i want to change by criteria**

```
    def result = db.rows('SELECT a.description FROM public."Description" as a ' +
                         'INNER JOIN public."product" as b ' +
                         'ON a.product_code =  b.product_code ' +
                         'WHERE a.product_code = ?',[productInstance.product_code])
```

Cuase instead return description : [description] , it returns description:[description_fielddb : description]

[image]

Now , in the controller i tried to replace with the following criteria

```
       List result = Description.withCriteria{
        product{
          eq('product_code', productInstance.product_code)
        }
        projections{
          property('description')
        }
      }
```

but product doesn't seems to be able to access :
[image]

**Description.groovy**

```
class Description {

String product_code;
String description; 

static belongsTo = [product : Product]
  static constraints = {
     product_code blank:false, size: 1..15
     description blank:false, size: 1..16

}
}
```

**Product.grovy**

```
class Product {

String store
String product_code
int price
String notes


static hasOne = [description: Description]

  static constraints = {
  product_code blank:false, size: 1..15
  price blank:false, scale: 2 
  store blank:false, size: 1..40
  notes blank:true , size: 1..150

 }  



product_code blank:false, size: 1..15
price blank:false, scale: 2 
store blank:false, size: 1..40
notes blank:true , size: 1..150

}
```

}

I tried `grails clean` and

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

i tried to delete the project from suite and re import too

Comment: Could you show code of domain classes  Description and product? Which version of grails are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a bigger picture of what you're doing? I find it odd that you're using Grails yet you're bypassing one of its best features: GORM/Hibernate. And you're domain model didn't make sense. I suspect you're working with an existing (aka. legacy) database, which is fine but that requires careful domain class mapping to make it work. For example, if `product_code` is the primary key of the product table, then GORM needs to know that; by default the primary key is `id`.

Comment: Im very new at grails , could you tell me why dont make sense ?

Comment: I update me question maybe can be more usefull

Comment: I suppose I should start with: why is the description in a separate domain class? I don't see the benefit. Don't worry about your ide not recognizing *product*. It's doing that because the method *product* does not exist; it's handled dynamically when the criteria query closure runs.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the domains and the query in a non grails way.

The domains has to be related properly

The mapping of product is not necessary cause your domain is called Product as well, Grails will generate the table "product". In other hand you have to relate its description. If there is a bidirectional relation. You have to use "hasOne"

```
class Product {

  String store
  String product_code
  int price
  String notes

  static hasOne = [description: Description]

  //or directly as a property. Don't do this if you use belongsTo in the other domain. 
  //Description description 

}
```

The description belongs to a product so it has to be related as "belongsTo"

```
class Description {

  String product_code
  String description

  static belongsTo = [product: Product]

}
```

If you want to get all the descriptions by the product code, you can create a criteria over the Description domain, by the property of the product, and getting the description property of the Description domain. Just do this:

```
List descriptions = Description.withCriteria{
  product{
    eq('product_code', productInstance.product_code)
  }
  projections{
    property('description')
  }
}
```

You don't need to create a Sql query in grails for that simple query.

Comment: As you recomend i only added in Class Description... static belongsTo = [Product: product]...but i get > Groovy:Apparent variable 'product' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:

Comment: I am very busy right now, but I could try to reproduce the error later. Could i ask you why are you starting with Grails from 2.x version? We are working with the 3.x one